# Why are multiple media queries not working?

Tags: css, media-queries

Trying to get multiple media queries to work on mobile but it only recognizes the first one and the second one does nothing. Please help and thanks.

It won't let me post without writing more text so just ignore this haha.

Again: It won't let me post without writing more text so just ignore this haha.

[link to application](http://ec2-54-85-190-233.compute-1.amazonaws.com/cocktailProject/)

```css
/* Medium sized screen */

@media all and (max-width: 1300px) {
  #left {
    width: 300px;
  }
  #right {
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
  }
  /* Filters */
  .filters {
    right: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    transition: right 1s;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50px;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
  }
  .filters .close {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 30px;
    right: 0;
  }
  .filters.show {
    right: 0;
  }
  .filtersIcon {
    display: flex;
  }
  /* Drink list */
  .totalDrinks {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }
  .drinkList {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/* Small screens */

@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
  #right {
    left: 100%
  }
  #left {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .drinkItem {
    min-height: 280px;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
I found the issue, I forgot to add this in the header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML and make a snippet so we can see it in action?

Comment: i think you should pass min-width value also.  If you will not pass min-width value it will apply for all devices up to width 1300px.

Answer (score 0):

It may work try this..

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
  //styles//
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write mobile first media queries. Kindle see the ref: [mobile first media queries](https://zellwk.com/blog/how-to-write-mobile-first-css/)

```
/* 
  ##Device = Desktops
  ##Screen = 1281px to higher resolution desktops
*/

@media (min-width: 1281px) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Laptops, Desktops
  ##Screen = B/w 1025px to 1280px
*/

@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (portrait)
  ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px
*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (landscape)
  ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px
*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Low Resolution Tablets, Mobiles (Landscape)
  ##Screen = B/w 481px to 767px
*/

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Most of the Smartphones Mobiles (Portrait)
  ##Screen = B/w 320px to 479px
*/

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {

  //CSS

}
```

[link](https://gist.github.com/gokulkrishh/242e68d1ee94ad05f488)

Comment: It depends on requirements and personal' decision.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to work with multiple media queries, there is a simple rule for that, that is **Order** (Arrangement) of the media queries.

In here, the main reason why the second one does nothing is because of the

> Query Clash.

Always query with ***Low pixel value works first*** and the ***Greater pixel value*** works.

**Note:**
Even after adding header also it's not work for sometimes, header also mandatory and with that **order of precedence** is much important.

***In your program,***

You've given first preference as 1300px. So, it overrides the other things upto 1300px (900px comes under 1300px. So that in here query clash occurs and you have given 1300px first so that it shows up not 900px).